# Getting length of HashTable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and trying to get the length of a HashTable (to use in a for loop), but I can't seem to get the length of the HashTable to output anything.

```
$user = @{}
$user[0] = @{}
$user[0]["name"] = "bswinnerton"
$user[0]["car"] = "honda"

$user[1] = @{}
$user[1]["name"] = "jschmoe"
$user[1]["car"] = "mazda"

write-output $user.length   #nothing outputs here

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $user.length; $i++)
{
    #write-output $user[0]["name"]
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`@{}` declares an HashTable whereas `@()` declares an Array

You can use

```
$user.count
```

to find the `length` of you `HashTable`.

If you do:

```
$user | get-member
```

you can see all the methods and properties of an object.

```
$user.gettype()
```

return the type of the object you have.

Comment: +1 For pointing out get-member. Somehow I never learned this and it will make things much easier in the future.

Answer (score 4):

`$user` is a hash table, so you should user`$user.count` instead.

Comment: Though note that (painfully) [everything has a `Length` an `Count` now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761715/1028230). Explanation at [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29761715/1028230).

Answer (score 1):

That's not an array but a hashtable. Use `.count` instead:

```
write-output $user.count
```