# Length property of DirectoryInfo object

Tags: powershell

There exists empty directory "New Folder" inside K:\test
    `>$a = gci K:\test`
Directory shouldn't have the Length property. Let's check:
    `[bool]($a.PSobject.Properties.Name -match "Length")
     False`

Yes, it doesn't have.
But:
   `>$a.Length
    1`

What does that mean???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a synthetic property that was added in V3, to prevent errors in scripts where an expression that would normally be expected to return an array may return a scalar, and cause array operations to fail.

> You can now use Count or Length on any object, even if it didn’t have the property.  If the object didn’t have a Count or Length property, it will will return 1 (or 0 for $null).  Objects that have Count or Length properties will continue to work as they always have.
>
> ```
> PS> $a = 42
> PS> $a.Count
> 1
> ```

[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20150612170424/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx) (archived link)

Comment: So  why then `$a | Measure-Object -Property length -sum` gets an error "length property not found"?

Comment: @Matt - Get-ChildItem may return one or more objects, but it's just a stream.  If there's more than one object returned, and the result is assigned to a variable or object property, then it becomes an array when it's "at rest". The creation of the array is a function of pipeline or indirection operations, not the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.

Comment: You are correct I was not giving enough information in my comment. How many items being returned influences the output is more of what I was getting at. Thanks for the tip